# Error: el divisor es igual a cero en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Necesito realizar la siguiente consulta `SQL` en `ORACLE`:

```
select 
        (DISPONIBILIDADES/EFECTIVO) as DISPONIBLE
    from sbv 
    where banco = 'ACTIVO (BU)'
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> ORA-01476: el divisor es igual a cero
>   01476. 00000 -  "divisor is equal to zero"

El campo `EFECTIVO` tiene como valor 0. Se que una división entre 0 da una indeterminación pero necesito que si la división es entre 0, me de como resultado 0.

Comment: Podrías hacer un CASE en donde indiques en la condición que cuando efectivo sea igual a 0 (Cero) retorne 0 (Cero)

Comment: @OtroBrayan esa es la respuesta.. armas una?

Comment: @gbianchi, te lo cedo! c;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para esto podemos usar un [case](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) para antes hacer la division chequear que el valor no sea 0.

```
select 
CASE EFECTIVO 
    WHEN 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (DISPONIBILIDADES/EFECTIVO) END as DISPONIBLE
from sbv 
where banco = 'ACTIVO (BU)'
```

Answer (score 5):

Generalmente es mejor aceptado que el resultado de esta división sea `NULL` y no cero, pues su significado es justamente *indeterminado*.

Para lograrlo, puedes valerte de la función [`nullif`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm):

```
select DISPONIBILIDADES / nullif(EFECTIVO, 0) as DISPONIBLE
  from sbv 
 where banco = 'ACTIVO (BU)'
```

Si de todas formas quieres que te devuelva cero, puedes valerte de `nvl()` o `coalesce():

```
select coalesce(DISPONIBILIDADES / nullif(EFECTIVO, 0), 0) as DISPONIBLE
  from sbv 
 where banco = 'ACTIVO (BU)'
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es tan buena o mejor que la mia :/

Comment: Creo que es la idea del sitio. :)